# Flutter health package - access denied! - Google fit

Tags: flutter, access-denied, google-fit

I am developing an app in Flutter with Health package, but my app isn´t working.

I download the google-services.json, already edited the manifest file with the package name and use the following permissions :

```
<uses-permission android:name="android.permission.INTERNET"/>
<uses-permission android:name="android.permission.ACTIVITY_RECOGNITION"/>
<uses-permission android:name="com.google.android.gms.permission.ACTIVITY_RECOGNITION"/>
<uses-permission android:name="android.permission.WRITE_EXTERNAL_STORAGE" />
<uses-permission android:name="android.permission.READ_EXTERNAL_STORAGE" />
<uses-permission android:name="android.permission.ACCESS_COARSE_LOCATION" />
<uses-permission android:name="android.permission.ACCESS_FINE_LOCATION" /
```

I  use the example I found in the page of this package:

```
// create a HealthFactory for use in the app
HealthFactory health = HealthFactory();

// define the types to get
var types = [
    HealthDataType.STEPS,
    HealthDataType.WEIGHT,
    HealthDataType.HEIGHT,
    HealthDataType.BLOOD_GLUCOSE,
];

// requesting access to the data types before reading them
bool requested = await health.requestAuthorization(types);

var now = DateTime.now();

// fetch health data from the last 24 hours
List<HealthDataPoint> healthData = await health.getHealthDataFromTypes(
    now.subtract(Duration(days: 1)), now, types);

// request permissions to write steps and blood glucose
types = [HealthDataType.STEPS, HealthDataType.BLOOD_GLUCOSE];
var permissions = [
    HealthDataAccess.READ_WRITE,
    HealthDataAccess.READ_WRITE
];  
await health.requestAuthorization(types, permissions: permissions);

// write steps and blood glucose 
bool success = await health.writeHealthData(10, HealthDataType.STEPS, now, now);
success = await health.writeHealthData(3.1, HealthDataType.BLOOD_GLUCOSE, now, now);

// get the number of steps for today
var midnight = DateTime(now.year, now.month, now.day);
int? steps = await health.getTotalStepsInInterval(midnight, now);
```

And the console log look like this:

```
D/FLUTTER_HEALTH(17489): Access Denied!
W/FLUTTER_HEALTH::ERROR(17489): There was an error adding the DataSet
W/FLUTTER_HEALTH::ERROR(17489): com.google.android.gms.common.api.ApiException: 4: The user must be signed in to make this API call.
W/FLUTTER_HEALTH::ERROR(17489):     at com.google.android.gms.common.internal.ApiExceptionUtil.fromStatus(com.google.android.gms:play-services-base@@18.0.1:3).
```

Please help me... I´ve tried for a long time :(

Comment: Hi, were able to solve it?

Answer (score -1):

The error says you must signed in to make API call. You must generate OAuth client IDs, handle scopes, etc in order to use the API. This is done through GCP. Also, make sure that the email is added as test user for your project.

Comment: Where do i need to add the test emails?
Do I need to upload load it to playstore?

Answer (score -1):

follow the nexts steps

-configure signature in the app, with keystore (build.gradle). view guidline
https://docs.flutter.dev/deployment/android

-configure oauth client

- view google-services.json with identical id client

and run!